# I receive 404 error only when submit secured url as value

Tags: php, forms, https, http-status-code-404

I receive 404 server error when submit `https://example.com/.../image.png` as value from a html form. When submit the same url with `http://` (not secured url) everything works fine.

Is there any restriction to submit `https://` urls as value of a form field?

My `.htaccess` file:

```
 redirect 301 /category/новини/ http://barimax.bg/новини/


ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?id=404

# Enable GZIP
<ifmodule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
</ifmodule>

# Expires Headers - 2678400s = 31 days
<ifmodule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 7200 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2678400 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2678400 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2678400 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 518400 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 2678400 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 2678400 seconds"
</ifmodule>

# Cache Headers
<ifmodule mod_headers.c>
  # Cache specified files for 31 days
  <filesmatch "\.(ico|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|css|swf)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2678400, public"
  </filesmatch>
  # Cache HTML files for a couple hours
  <filesmatch "\.(html|htm)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=7200, private, must-revalidate"
  </filesmatch>
  # Cache PDFs for a day
  <filesmatch "\.(pdf)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=86400, public"
  </filesmatch>
  # Cache Javascripts for 31 days
  <filesmatch "\.(js)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2678400, private"
  </filesmatch>
</ifmodule>

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
# First rewrite to HTTPS:
# Don't put www. here. If it is already there it will be included, if not
# the subsequent rule will catch it.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !ckfinder.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://barimax.bg/$1/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^barimax.bg [NC,OR]
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.barimax.bg .com [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.barimax.bg/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

AuthName "www"
AuthUserFile "/home/barimax/.htpasswds/public_html/passwd"


AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54  .php54 .php
```

Comment: You need to change/add the code in `.htaccess` file.

Comment: may be a spelling mistake. but you have to use `https://example.com`

Comment: @prava Thank you for comment. I also think that the problem is in `.htaccess`, but I don't know where.

Comment: It will be helpful, if you post your htaccess code.

Comment: Okay, got the code, let me check once.

Comment: Sorry for late response. Check this one - http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/http-https-rewriterule-redirect.html

Comment: @prava I checked the link I will make some experiments. But I can not figure out why rewrite rules affect form field submition. I acctually send the url as field value. The `action=""` attribute is set correct because when I send field value with `http://` it works correct.